# How to Convert Decimal to DateTime in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, decimal, converters

I'm trying to Convert a Decimal DateTime value to DateTime datatype and check a condition in a select query

```
SELECT * FROM CLBALTRNTBL WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME,LSTDAT) >= @sDt 
      AND CONVERT(DATETIME,LSTDAT) <= @eDt
```

but the following error Occurs

```
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.
```

I'm doing this in a stored Procedure. and the `@sDt`and `@eDt` are `DateTime` Variables. The `LSTDAT` is in the format `yyyyMMdd`ie `20120317`

But if I enter the `LSTDAT` column directly ,for ex:`20130805`, the query executes. but what with the column??

Can you help me out ?

Comment: I think there is `Set DateFormat` present prior to SP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT *
FROM CLBALTRNTBL
WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), LSTDAT), 112) >= @sDt
    AND CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), LSTDAT), 112) <= @eDt
```

Answer (score 3):

It's way more efficient to convert your variables and compare to column - than to convert your column.

```
SELECT * 
FROM CLBALTRNTBL 
WHERE LSTDAT >= CONVERT(INT,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8),@sDt,112))
  AND LSTDAT <= CONVERT(INT,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8),@eDt,112))
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/30803/1)**

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM CLBALTRNTBL WHERE LSTDAT >= convert(char(8),@sDt, 112) 
AND CONVERT(DATETIME,LSTDAT) <= convert(char(8),@eDt, 112)
```

This will prevent your errors and perform faster, however your do have some invalid LSTDAT in the base that cannot be converted to dates

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM CLBALTRNTBL WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME,LSTDAT) >= @sDt 
      AND CONVERT(DATETIME,Convert(VarChar(8),LSTDAT),112) <= @eDt
```

would be one way.

e.g. 20120317 to '20120317' then 112 is ISO format yyyyMMdd

Comment: I'm a twit should have been varchar(8)